# Java 8 Streams how to sum a total based on a list of strings

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using a java stream, how do i perform a conditional calculation based on a list of Strings (shopping clothes)?

So if a shirt costs 10.5 and jeans cost 9.5 then the one shirt and one jeans should cost 20

```
    double totalCost = 0;
    List <String> shopping = Arrays.asList("Shirt", "Jeans");
    shopping.stream()
    .forEach(string -> {
        if (string.equals("Shirt")) {
            totalCost += 10.5d;
        } else if (string.equals("Jeans")) {
            totalCost += 9.5d;
        } 
    });
    System.out.println(totalCost);
```

The above code doesnt even compile because it wont let me use `totalCost`  inside the stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot modify local variables from a lambda expression. Instead, use a combination of `mapToDouble` and `sum`:

```
double totalCost = Arrays.asList("Shirt", "Jeans").stream().mapToDouble(string -> {
    if (string.equals("Shirt")) {
        return 10.5d;
    } else if (string.equals("Jeans")) {
        return 9.5d;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}).sum();
System.out.println(totalCost);
```

BTW: You really should not use double for money.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't use double. IEEE 754 is very problematic. Consider the following example:

```
System.out.println(0.1d + 0.2d);
```

Result:

```
0.30000000000000004
```

I would use BigDecimal and map of items' costs.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    final Map<String, BigDecimal> itemCosts = ImmutableMap.of(
            "Shirt", new BigDecimal("10.5"),
            "Jeans", new BigDecimal("9.5"));
    final BigDecimal sum = ImmutableList.of("Shirt", "Jeans", "Something").stream()
            .map(item -> itemCosts.getOrDefault(item, BigDecimal.ZERO))
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```